# How to extract data from a list of tuples which length could be variable

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list which contains multiple tuples (the length of items is variable) and I want to extract some specific data located at the same rank inside the tuples.

Let me show you an example. Let's work on this list of 3 tuples:

```
x = [
    ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'), 
    ('e5', 'f6', 'g7', 'h8'), 
    ('i9', 'j10', 'k11', 'l12')
]
```

I want to retrieve the fourth items of each tuples. I use the length of the list within a `While` loop:

```
y = len(x)
while y > 0:
    print(x[0][3])
    y = y - 1
```

The result I get is:

```
d4
d4
d4
```

But I want the following result:

```
d4
h8
l12
```

Is there a way to replace the `[0]` by the **y** variable inside this section `print(x[0][3])` to get the result I want?

Comment: You're literally printing `print(x[0][3])` which is a constant value, each time in the loop.

Comment: yes. `print(x[y][3])`

Comment: `print(x[y][3])` gives me this _IndexError: list index out of range_

Comment: @FrançoiseDionisi that's because `y` is counting backwards, you could have instead done `while y < len(x)` starting at 0 but a for loop makes much more sense.

Comment: yes. y starts off being the length of x. Python uses 0-indexed lists. the largest index in range is `len(x) - 1`

Comment: @Dan 's suggestion for a for loop is best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more natural to use a for loop for this:

```
for item in x:
    print(item[3])
```

The reason your code didn't work was because you had hard-coded it to always get the first tuple in your list i.e. in `print(x[0][3])` the `0` in `x[0]` needed to be a variable that iterates through your list. This would be easier if you count up instead of down i.e.

```
counter = 0
while counter < len(x):
    print(x[counter][3])
    counter += 1
```

but it really doesn't make sense to use `while` for this when `for` exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
for tup in x :
   print(tup[3])
```

Comment: but don't use `tuple` as a variable name :)

Comment: yes that might be a bad habit to give like those names for variables. But here it should work with no problem.

Comment: Thank you. Easy :)

Comment: It won't cause a problem here but it might cause some very strange bugs down the line. You should really edit the answer and change it.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple iterate on them and once you done you will get the tuples only like the following

```
('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4')
('e5', 'f6', 'g7', 'h8') 
('i9', 'j10', 'k11', 'l12')
```

and once you get them index on each tuple to get the last value like `[-1]` or `[len(tuples) - 1]`
**and the following are my codes**

```
x = [
    ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'), 
    ('e5', 'f6', 'g7', 'h8'), 
    ('i9', 'j10', 'k11', 'l12')
]

read = [i[-1] for i in x]
print(read)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[each_tuple[-1] for each_tuple in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
y = len(x)
while y>0:
    print(x[len(x)-y][3])
    y = y-1
```

Output:-

```
d4
h8
l12
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**
`for loop`

```
x = [
    ('a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'), 
    ('e5', 'f6', 'g7', 'h8'), 
    ('i9', 'j10', 'k11', 'l12')
]

for y in x:
    print(y[3])
```

`While loop`

```
c = len(x)-1
while c>=0:
    print(x[c][-1])
    c-=1
```

Comment: @Gad The above code is working why did you rejected?

Comment: what do you mean by reject